# How can make random images come out from the holes in Whack-a-Mole game instead of one image

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering would someone be able to help me to show me a way to be able to bring out random images from the holes instead of one image in a Whack a mole game on Javascript. 
The following is the function used for an image to come up in random holes. Currently its only one image but I'd like it to be about 10 different images coming out.

```
var wormImg = new Image();
var worm;

wormImg.src = 'hobby.png';
wormImg.name = 'worm';
wormImg.onload = loadGfx;

function showWorm()
{
if(currentWorms == totalWorms)
{
    showAlert();
}
else
{   
    if(lastWorm != null)
    {
        lastWorm.onPress = null;
        stage.removeChild(lastWorm);
        stage.update();
        lastWorm = null;
    }

    var randomPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);

    var worm = new Bitmap (wormImg); 

    worm.x = wormsX[randomPos];
    worm.y = wormsY[randomPos];
    stage.addChild(worm);
    worm.onPress = wormHit;

    lastWorm = worm;
    lastWorm.scaleY = 0.3;
    lastWorm.y += 42;
    stage.update();

    Tween.get(lastWorm).to({scaleY: 1, y: wormsY[randomPos]}, 200).wait(1000).call(function(){currentWorms++; showWorm()});
}
}
```

I would appreciate any help, thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you know what ["your" current code](http://tutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tutspremium/flash-rias/055_easelJSWhackAWorm/Final/worms.html) is doing? What have you tried to expand it?

Comment: Well i didn't claim it was my code and I don't see why you answered in such way. Not everyone is professional in coding and there are people trying to learn. I asked nicely for someones help if you wasn't going to help you dont need to reply.

Comment: I don't know what 'way' you refer to. If you are learning, we expect you to try something. You didn't write code yourself, but instead pasted it from a tutorial, without even mentioning it (attribution would be in place). Stack Overflow is not a code generation service, and to get good answers we would like to see that you have tried something and have a basic knowledge so you can at least understand the answers that we give. So, regarding that, I thought my initial comment was quite friendly actually.

Comment: I don't know what other people do but the only reason I pst here is to get help when I'm stuck, which means I have already tried somethings and for some reason they didn't work out and instead of posting everything I tried I just posted this to see if I could get any directions. Also why would I post a question just to get the ready code from others, how would that benefit me and how would I learn?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array of possible values for worm.src, and randomly select one whenever showing a new worm

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I was wondering would you be able to help me a bite more with this since Im sure you understood Im a beginner.

This is how I tried to create the arrays, 


   `var imgArray = new Array();
    imgArray[0] = new Image();
    imgArray[0].src = 'img/worm1.jpg';

    imgArray[1] = new Image();
    imgArray[1].src = 'img/worm2.jpg';`


and I tried to randomly select them with math.random but it didn't work, can you tell me where I'm going wrong please

Comment: I'd need more information about how it "didn't work" (Error? Not getting the result you wanted?), but are you initializing the name and onload for each image in the array?

Comment: When I say it didn't work none of the images appeared in the screen. the previous array code is the whole thing I did.

Comment: Might be simpler to just store the worm.src values in an array, and set wormImg.scr randomly before the line `var worm = new Bitmap (wormImg);`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help